# I have an error when loading wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, iis, wamp

I have this site but the css files do not seem to load correctly :http://185.58.193.198:12500/HelpDesk/
Can some tell me what changes i should make. I have used wamp for the database and IIS for hosting

Comment: You have CORS error, CSS is point to localhost !

Comment: Post the error here.

Answer (score 0):

There many reasons for 403 error, you can try to add below code in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and you can also try enabled anonymous authentication in iis authentication.